# Optimal Data Structure in Elixir for frequent updates, item removal and subset creation based on value

Tags: elixir

*I am working on a project I plucked out of the sky for fun to better understand Erlang, Elixir and functional data structures.  I am asking this question to gain some insight to best data structure(s) for the following scenarios as a learning exercise and to see if there is a single ideal candidate in the standard lib which satisfies the following scenarios.*

I wish to keep an in memory store.  I am wondering which backing data structure would be fit for purpose for the following scenario:

- Potentially tens of thousands (or more) entries.
- Frequent inserts and updates of each entry.
- Periodic scans (think gc runs) to remove stale items (e.g. items not updated within last X seconds)
- Querying to produce subset (e.g. all updated in last X seconds)

Some background:

- Client server scenario where each connected client corresponds to a single entry in the backing store where the key is the client id.
- Each client will send updated data every x seconds. (Frequently)
- When the client disconnects the item in the backing store will be removed.
- Each entry in the backing store will also be removed if it hasn't been updated in the last X seconds. (To handle removing stale data when disconnect was not received)

I'm currently using a HashDict backed Process which, is the simplest possible thing, knowing that there could be potentially a large number of entries, and this would allow fast random access updates as the key would correspond to the client id.  The value at present is a Map which itself would contain the "last_updated" time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan on having a large number of concurrently connected clients, then using a single process may present a bottleneck. Instead, you could use an ETS table to store your data. This would allow better CPU usage, since multiple clients may query and modify the table concurrently.

One way to approach this is to use per-client GenServer, and the [gproc](https://github.com/uwiger/gproc) library which under the hood relies on ETS to provide rich aliases to processes. So you may give your client-specific processes names such as `{client, 1}`, `{client, 2}` and so on. Then, when a request arrives, you first try to find the client via gproc, and if it doesn't exist, you create it. The latter part must go through a well-defined singleton process, to avoid race conditions. Once you find the client, you simply make the request to that client.

You can implement the timeout logic in the client-specific process. Essentially, from your handle_* and init callbacks, you can specify the timeout in milliseconds. If a new message doesn't arrive in the given time, your client process will receive a timeout message, which you can handle in handle_info and have the receiving process stop. Once a process stops, it will be automatically deregisterd from gproc registry. In the supervision tree, these processes should obviously be temporary or transient workers, to prevent supervisors from restarting them.

An alternative option is to keep everything in ETS without relying on client processes. You'll need some kind of expiry logic to GC unused entries, and this is done manually. A simplistic brute force way is to traverse the entire table periodically and delete old entries. Or you can devise something more intelligent. I've used one version of this technique in my previous project, and made a helper library available [here](https://github.com/sasa1977/con_cache).

Comment: con_cache project looks great, will enjoy reading the code.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks! Just to be completely clear, I think the first approach (client specific processes + gproc discovery + in-process timeout) is more idiomatic, and I would first try this approach. In fact thinking back, I believe this approach might be more suitable for the system where con_cache originated. The only downside is that it requires some more boilerplate, whereas con_cache already has some things implemented (such as GCing and notifications).